# Is it more efficient to query my mongodb database for a list of exactly what I want or querying a superset and doing list comprehension?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

In my *products* collection I have documents that have fields such as *name*, *category* and *variant*. Here is an example, note that I am only showing the relevant fields.

```
{"name": "iPhone X", "category": "Phones", "variant": "Black"}
{"name": "iPhone X", "category": "Phones", "variant": "Grey"}
{"name": "iPad Air", "category": "Tablets", "variant": "Black"}
{"name": "iPad Air", "category": "Tablets", "variant": "Silver"}
```

> I would like a list of product objects that contain products from a
>   specified category and only one product for each name (in that specified category).

Here is my python code for doing this the 'list comprehension way'. I feel like this is not the best way of doing it and would be appreciative to know better way. I would also be curious to know if in this case and perhaps in more general cases as well, if it is better to query exactly what you want from the database or query for a superset and then use list comprehension in python to filter out the data that you want. In my case (below) I do two queries which I am pretty sure is not a great way to do it either!

**My way of doing it:**

In my *Product* class I have the following:

```
 @classmethod
 def find_all_by_category(cls, category):
    return [cls(**elem) for elem in Database.find(ProductConstants.COLLECTION, {'category': category})]

 @classmethod
 def find_one_by_name(cls, name):
        return cls(**Database.find_one(ProductConstants.COLLECTION, {'name': name}))
```

This returns a list of Product objects that have a specified category.

**In a seperate class I have the following method**

```
@staticmethod
def list_of_unique_names_in_category(category)
    products_in_category = Product.find_all_by_category(category)
    product_names_in_category = [product.name for product in 
    products_in_category]

    return [Product.find_one_by_name(name) for name in product_names_in_category]
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: what about doing some tests?

Comment: Absolutely, but I do not know of an alternative way of doing it to test it against.

Comment: This doesn't do what you want, because `product_names_in_category` has duplicate names. I'd argue the more clear way to do this is construct a dict keyed by name: `{p.name: p for p in Product.find_all_by_category(category)}.values()`

Comment: Also use generators when possible, because building up a list requires allocating space for everything (you can `list()` the return from your DB class methods if need be, but this should be a decision by the consumer of this API)

Comment: A good database, when used correctly, can do indexing to filter results much more efficiently than the O(n) code you'd run at the application level. Not saying that Mongo is a good database, or that you're using it correctly -- but *in general*, this should be left to the database layer.

Comment: `list_of_unique_names_in_category` already returns a list of Product objects on the call to `Product.find_all_by_category`. It's inefficient calling `Product.find_one_by_name` again for each `Product` object in the result of the earlier query. You currently have an N+1 problem in your hands.

Answer (score 0):

How i do is, I will build the logic to set a flag select:true, and then just though a query with select: true condition. 
So the flag setting is a one time job, whenever you add a new product. This simplifies the query and minimizes the data retrieval from mongodb.

```
{"name": "iPhone X", "category": "Phones", "variant": "Black", "select": true}
{"name": "iPhone X", "category": "Phones", "variant": "Grey"}
{"name": "iPad Air", "category": "Tablets", "variant": "Black", "select": true}
{"name": "iPad Air", "category": "Tablets", "variant": "Silver"}
```